# kendo ui: how to remove a dataItem of a dataSource bound to some comboBox, inside combobox dataBound event

Tags: combobox, kendo-ui, datasource

I have a grid, inside of some column of which I have created a combobox editing UI, using columns.editor function.
My goal is every time a user selects some value from the combobox -while populating a newly created grid record-, this value to be
removed from the list options of a next record's combobox.

One of the things i've tried is shown below:

```
function equipmentDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    var equipmentComboBox = $('<input id="equipmentDropDownEditor" required data-text-field="name" data-value-field="name" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoComboBox({
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: equipmentTypesDS,
            dataBound: function(e) {

              var equipmentData = e.sender.dataSource.data();

              if(currentlyInsertedEquipmentTypes.length > 0){

                for(var i=0;i<currentlyInsertedEquipmentTypes.length;i++){

                    $.each( equipmentData, function( index, selectedEquipmentData ) {

                            if (selectedEquipmentData.name == currentlyInsertedEquipmentTypes[i]){

                                  var dataItem = e.sender.dataSource.at(index);
                                  console.log("dataItem: " + dataItem.name + " is being removed");
                                  e.sender.dataSource.remove(dataItem);

                            }
                    });
                }

              }

            }
        });
}
```

I've created a global array variable named "currentlyInsertedEquipmentTypes" inside of which I hold all the user's already selected values
(for example if the user has created 2 records inside the grid and has selected "laptop" option in the combobox of the first and "workstation" option
in the combobox of the second --> currentlyInsertedEquipmentTypes = ["laptop", "workstation"] ).

Inside the combobox dataBound event I check whether the user has already selected values (currentlyInsertedEquipmentTypes.length>0)
and if he has, I locate the corresponding object inside the bound dataSource and I remove it, so that it wont be available in the next record's combobox list.
This is where the whole thing crashes even though the data item removal takes place.

Am i missing something that i should do after the data item removal? Should i rebind the datasource to the combobox in some way?
Any help would be much appreciated.

[EDIT]

---- The combobox datasource code

var equipmentTypesDS=  new kendo.data.DataSource({

```
transport: {
    read: {
        url: "api/equipment_types",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            //"equipment_category": 1
        },
        dataType: "json"
    }
},
schema: {
    data: "data",
    total: "total"
}
```

});

--- the kendo grid code:

```
                    $("#popup_equipment").kendoGrid({  
                        dataSource: {
                            schema:{
                                model:{
                                    id: "equipment_type_id",
                                    fields:{
                                        equipment_type_id: { editable: false },
                                        name: { }, //validation: {required: true}, defaultValue: "LAPTOP", 
                                        items:{ type: "number", defaultValue:1, validation: { required: true, min: 1} }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        toolbar: ["create"],
                        columns: [
                            { field: "name", title: "εξοπλισμός", width: "300px", editor: equipmentDropDownEditor, template: "#=name#" },
                            { field: "items", title:"πλήθος", width: "80px"},
                            { command: ["destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "100px" }
                        ],
                        //editable: "inline",//true,
                        editable:{confirmation: false},
                        scrollable: false,
                        selectable: false
                     });
```

[EDIT 2]

```
$("#popup_equipment").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        schema:{
            model:{
                id: "equipment_type_id",
                fields:{
                    equipment_type_id: { editable: false },
                    name: { }, //validation: {required: true}, defaultValue: "LAPTOP", 
                    items:{ type: "number", defaultValue:1, validation: { required: true, min: 1} }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns: [
        { field: "name", title: "εξοπλισμός", width: "60%", editor: equipmentDropDownEditor, template: "#=name#" },
        { field: "items", title:"πλήθος", width: "20%"},
        { command: ["destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "20%" }
    ],
    editable:{confirmation: false},
    scrollable: false,
    selectable: false,
    save: function(e){
        console.log("GRID SAVE EVENT! ", e);
        var equipment_name = e.values.name;
        equipmentTypesDS.get(equipment_name).used = true;
        console.log("equipmentTypesDS", equipmentTypesDS);
        console.log("END OF GRID SAVE EVENT!");
    }
});




function equipmentDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    var equipmentComboBox = $('<input id="equipmentDropDownEditor" required data-text-field="name" data-value-field="name" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoComboBox({
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: equipmentTypesDS,
        });
}


var equipmentTypesDS=  new kendo.data.DataSource({

    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "api/equipment_types",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                //"equipment_category": 1
            },
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: "data",
        total: "total",
        model:{
            id: "name"
        }
    },
    filter: { field: "used", operator: "neq", value: true }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach. Instead of removing the element filter it out.

Example: I define a DataSource with a list of Cities (your Inserted Equipment) as follow:

```
var cityDS = new kendo.data.DataSource ({
    data : [
        { City : "Seattle", used : false },
        { City : "Tacoma", used : false },
        { City : "Kirkland", used : false },
        { City : "Redmond", used : false },
        { City : "London", used : false },
        { City : "Philadelphia", used : false },
        { City : "New York", used : false },
        { City : "Boston", used : false }
    ],
    schema : {
        model : {
            id : "City"
        }
    },
    filter: { field: "used", operator: "eq", value: false }
});
```

As you can see I added a field called `used` that simply says if that `City` is already used or not. And I set it as `id` of this DataSource. In addition, I set a `filter` saying that I only want those where `used` id equal (`eq`) to `false`.

The editor function is pretty much yours:

```
function cityDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    var equipmentComboBox = $('<input required data-text-field="City" data-value-field="City" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoComboBox({
        autoBind: false,
        dataSource: cityDS
    });
}
```

but with no `dataBound` or any other event handler.

Finally in the `Grid` when I save a record, I `filter` that city from the list. Something like:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    editable  : "popup",
    pageable  : true,
    toolbar: [ "create" ],
    columns   :
    [
        { field: "FirstName", width: 90, title: "First Name" },
        { field: "LastName", width: 200, title: "Last Name" },
        { field: "City", width: 200, editor : cityDropDownEditor }
    ],
    save : function(e) {
        console.log("e", e);
        var city = e.model.City;
        cityDS.get(city).used = true;
    }
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

This might work if you start the Grid with no elements otherwise you would have to conveniently initialize the `used` field. It might require some additional code dealing with cases as changing the `City` but from your description, doesn't seem to be the case.

You can see this running here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/ZH4aD/

Comment: Hello OnaBai and thanks for your quick response.
Unfortunately I have a problem in applying your solution to my case.
My bad I didn't cite the whole code related to the problem, i just added some code to my question above.

You can see the datasource which will be bound to the combobox of the grid.I am not the one who creates the data. I get them by making an API request.From what I've checked, kendo datasource documentation does not offer a way to add a new field to a datasource. If that is the case is there another way round to the problem?

Comment: They don't mention how to add fields because in JavaScript you don't need to declare them, you can do it whenever you want. Since you are not receiving `used` what you can assume is that if for a record it is not defined it is because that `City` is not being used. Check my  modified JSFiddle showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/ZH4aD/2 (Please check that now the condition is for `neq` to `true` matching both if it is false as well as it is not defined).

Comment: i followed your example but the save event gets triggred every time i press the down arrow in order to make a selection,  so the "used" attribute is set to true for every item located above the one i finally select in the list. As a result many items are filtered though they shouldn't. In your case the save event doesnt get triggered though .. any idea what could cause this behavior? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you say about the "save" being executed when you press down arrow. Which edition mode are you using (popup, inline, ...)? Can you share some code that reproduces what you say? Does it happen to you with my JSFiddle?

Comment: Below [EDIT 2] you can see my new code. I use inline edition mode. There are two ways in selecting an item from a combobox. The first is by opening the list with the mouse and selecting the proper item. The other is to press the keybord's down arrow and navigate to the proper item, passing one by one the items above it in the list. In the second case, when i press the down arrow, the grid's save event gets triggered and this code    cityDS.get(city).used = true;     is executed. So if the item i want to select its fifth in the list i set the used attribute for all four items above it.

Comment: What i described does not happen to your example in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Which OS/Browser are you using? I've tested it (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/ZH4aD/2) in OSX/Chrome and does not invoke save each time I press arrow down but only when I click on update. Actually `save` event (by KendoUI documentation) should not be invoked  until you press "update" in the popup window.

Comment: it happens in firefox 25.0.1 as well as in chrome  31.0.1650.57 m. OS windows 7

Comment: actually no matter what edit mode i choose (inline, popup), it provides the inline functionality, which is weird.

Comment: I've tried the JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/ZH4aD/2) as it is in Windows 7 and Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 m and works fine. Same with Firefox 25.0.1. So if you run my code as it is from JSFiddle site there is something else.